# Multiple instances of Tabify, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to have multiple instances of a tabbed content box, only for some reason I cant get it working...

is it possible to add a loop to the function with .each() ?

http://jsfiddle.net/zAJVK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Z3PZt/

You need to uniquely identify the tabs on the second tabset. Works now...